# Self-loop edges working with OrientDB Graphs

Tags: graph, orientdb, java, orientdb2.2

I tried to create a self-loops edge in a OrientDB Graph through Java API.

```
graph.addEdge("class:hasChild", 
                    graph.getVerticesOfClass(domain).iterator().next(),
                    graph.getVerticesOfClass(range).iterator().next(),
                    "hasChild");
```

From Orient Studio, I saw in SCHEMA that it creates the edge "hasChild" with 0 records.

When I displayed the graph with `select from V`, I didn't see the edge "hasChild", but it allow me to create it manually.
Why is this happening? 
I need to create it by Java API

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Vertex v1 = graph.getVerticesOfClass(domain).iterator().next();
 Vertex v2 = graph.getVerticesOfClass(range).iterator().next();
 v1.addEdge("hasChild", v2);
```

Comment: which is the problem? that you do not see in Graph Editor?

Comment: I didn't see the self-loop edge in Graph Editor. Clicking on outgoing edges of the interested vertex, the self-loop edge doesn't appear. Furthermore, in the form SCHEMA the self-loop edge has 0 records.